# What happens to metal when exposed to an electric current for an extended period of time?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, conductors, metals

I was wondering what happens to the actual metal (copper, aluminum, silver, gold) when electricity is ran through it for a long period of time. Say years like the wire in a house. Does the conductivity of the metal decrease because of the metal being heated for so long? It gets hot  in attics during summer so I am sure the wire gets extremely hot added with the wire being in a coating. Or does the metal begin to degrade after years of having a current ran through it and the flow weakens?

Comment: You mean the phenomenon of electromigration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration? It's not much of a problem in household circuits, but it does pose challenges e.g. in semiconductor devices.